# Jinja 2 Templates: how I check in an if statement whether the boolean is False or None

Tags: python, jinja2

So I want to show in a jinja2 template whether a state is `True`, `False` or `None`.
Naturally I use a boolean since I have there the three states I need.

So I tried the following code to show the `True` and the `False` state and wanted to show nothing when it's `None`.

```
            {% if valid %}
            VALID
            {% elif not valid %}
            NOT VALID
            {%endif %}
```

But my problem is now that when `valid` is `None` it shows `'NOT VALID'`
How I can change that to showing nothing instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write `if valid is none`. Note that `is` in Jinja is not the same as Python's `is`. In this case `is` calls a Jinja filter named `none`. [Here is the list of built-in filters.](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#filters)

```
jinja2.Template('{% if a is none %}None{% endif %}').render(a=None)
u'None'
jinja2.Template('{% if a is none %}None{% endif %}').render(a=False)
u''
```